# Associating ngx-timepicker-field with input

Tags: angular, timepicker

I want to associate input with ngx-timepicker-field from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-material-timepicker. It work's when I use ngx-material-timepicker like this:

```
<input
 matInput
 [ngxTimepicker]="picker"
 [format]="24"
/>
<ngx-material-timepicker #picker></ngx-material-timepicker>
```

but when i only change

```
<ngx-material-timepicker #picker></ngx-material-timepicker>
```

into

```
<ngx-timepicker-field #picker></ngx-timepicker-field>
```

I get errors:

```
SingularActionDesignComponent.html:13 ERROR TypeError: this._timepicker.registerInput is not a function
    at TimepickerDirective.registerTimepicker (ngx-material-timepicker.js:764)
    at TimepickerDirective.set timepicker [as timepicker] (ngx-material-timepicker.js:699)
    at updateProp (core.js:32189)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31871)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44367)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44306)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45328)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45271)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (SingularActionDesignComponent.html:34)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:45259)
```

eventually is there any other good non-bootstrap library for timepicking?

Comment: The Field should be used on its own, have a look at the demo: https://agranom.github.io/ngx-material-timepicker/

Comment: There are some non bootstrap libraries: https://github.com/SteveDunlap13/MaterialTimeControl
https://github.com/owsolutions/amazing-time-picker

Comment: Here is the tracking issue from the angular repo with alternatives in the comments. https://github.com/angular/components/issues/5648